# How do I use Normalizr to handle basic nested JSON?

Tags: redux, normalizr

I have a very standard nested JSON response.  **Projects** have many **dashboards**. **Dashboards** have many **charts**.

What is the right way to define and use my schemas?

*Below is the code for my Schemas.js, my API response, and what Normalizr converts my API response into.*

Schemas.js:

```
import { Schema, arrayOf, normalize } from 'normalizr';

// Create a schema for each model.
const project = new Schema('projects');
const dashboard = new Schema('dashboard');
const chart = new Schema('chart');

// Projects have many dashboards.
project.define({
  dashboards: arrayOf(dashboard)
});

// Dashboards have many charts.
dashboard.define({
  charts: arrayOf(chart)
});

export const Schemas = { project, dashboard, chart };
```

My API response:

```
{
  projects: [{
    id: 1,
    name: "Project 1",
    dashboards: [{
      id: 1,
      name: "Dashboard 1",
      charts: [{
        id: 1,
        name: "Chart 1"
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: "Chart 2"
      }]
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: "Dashboard 2",
      charts: [{
        id: 3,
        name: "Chart 3"
      },
      {
        id: 4,
        name: "Chart 4"
      }]
    }]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "Project 2",
    dashboards: [{
      id: 3,
      name: "Dashboard",
      charts: []
    }]
  }]
}
```

When I receive this JSON in an action I do `normalize(response, Schemas.project);`. This seems to move the entire response into `entities.projects.undefined`.

```
{
  entities: {
    projects: {
      undefined: {
        projects: [{
          id: 1,
          name: "Project 1",
          ...
        }, ...]
      }
    }
  },
  result: undefined
}
```

How should I correctly define and use my schemas for this?

**References:**

https://github.com/gaearon/normalizr

https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/master/examples/real-world/actions/index.js

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should give you the desired result:

```
normalize(response, {
    projects: arrayOf(Schemas.project)
});
```

The projects key is nescessary because you have an extra key in your response, and the arrayOf() indicates that the API returns an array of results.

Comment: Is there a way to achieve the same if I didn't know in advance that this key will be called projects? Say this was a list of reports grouped by categories, so instead of projects, I will just have a name of category and then an array of objects for reports.

Comment: you are probably better off structuring your API slightly different by making sure the key is always the same (if you have the flexibility to do that). Like two keys with 'name' and 'reports' for example.

Comment: yeah did that eventually. Figured out that grouping at API response side was not that productive afterall.